# Ansible node not able to access a file in my host System

Tags: macos, centos, ansible

I am trying to copy a file from my Host Mac System to CentOS on a VM through Ansible Roles.

I have a folder created called Ansible Roles and under that I have used ansible-galaxy command and have created a role called tomcatdoccfg. helloworld.war is present in the root Ansible Roles folder.

The folder structure is as below :
[image]

Ansible tasks\main.yml playbook on Mac is as below:

```js
- name: Copy war file to tmp
  copy:
    src: ⁨helloworld.war
    dest: /tmp/helloworld.war
```

The helloworld.war file should be accessible for user abhilashdk(My Default MAC username). The CentOS VM also has a user called abhilashdk. I have configured ssh keys. Meaning I have generated ssh-keys -t rsa and moved the keys to the CentOS VM using ssh-copy-id and I am able to ping to VM using   `ansible -i hosts node1 -m ping` command. I am able to install docker also on my node1 machine using ansible.

I have a main.yml file in the root Ansible Roles folder the contents of which is as below:

```js
---
- hosts: node1
  vars:
    webapp:
      app1:
        PORT: 8090
        NAME: webapp1
      app2:
        PORT: 8091
        NAME: webapp2
  become: true
  roles:
    - docinstall
    - tomcatdoccfg
```

Now when I run the command `ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yml`  I get the below error for Copy war file to tmp:

`TASK [tomcatdoccfg : Copy war file to tmp] ************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was:    /Files/DevOps/Ansible/Ansible_roles/⁨helloworld.war
fatal: [node1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Could not find or access '⁨helloworld.war'\nSearched in:\n\t/Files/DevOps/Ansible/Ansible_roles/tomcatdoccfg/files/⁨helloworld.war\n\t/Files/DevOps/Ansible/Ansible_roles/tomcatdoccfg/⁨helloworld.war\n\t/Files/DevOps/Ansible/Ansible_roles/tomcatdoccfg/tasks/files/⁨helloworld.war\n\t/Files/DevOps/Ansible/Ansible_roles/tomcatdoccfg/tasks/⁨helloworld.war\n\t/Files/DevOps/Ansible/Ansible_roles/files/⁨helloworld.war\n\t/Files/DevOps/Ansible/Ansible_roles/⁨helloworld.war"}`

I am not understanding what permissions should I give to hellowrold.war file so that my centos on vm will be able to access it through ansible playbook/roles.

Could anybody help me out how to solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i copied the full text of the error you get and pasted to notepad++, and i see a strange non-latin character symbol prefixing the file name: `⁨helloworld.war`. Could you check the `tasks.yml` file, perhaps some encoding issue?

Comment: Hi @ilias-sp I checked and did not find any such characters.

Comment: i added an answer, so i could attach a picture to show you the "hidden" character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding as answer, so i can show the non-latin characters that the log you attached in the question includes:

note right before the `helloworld.war`.
[image: log]

Could be the reason why Ansible cant find the file on the FS.
To be on the safe side, i would delete the whole `main.yml` and rewrite it.

Comment: Thanks. I will re write and give it a try.

Comment: Hi @ilias-sp. Thank you. I just deleted the `src:helloworld` line and re-wrote it. It worked. Now I remember copy pasting the file location from the Get Info menu on helloworld.war file. My Bad. I learnt one thing, never copy paste, even the file path :p

Answer (score -1):

`ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yml --ask-sudo-pass` or `ansible-playbook -i hosts main.yml --ask-pass`
This params will ask you for sudo password for playbook operations